# Export An Env Var To Container With Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'd like to export an environment variable to Docker using Ansible (preferably) that has a value of a command substitution, e.g.

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=`cat /root/file.txt`
```

`file.txt`'s content changes from time to time, therefore I need the command substitution to dynamically change the var's value.

What is the way to achieve such thing ? I tried

```
env:
  SSH_AUTH_SOCK="`cat /root/file.txt`"
```

but it appended the literal string rather than its value.

Answer (score 1):

This way it will most likely not work.

Execute  the `cat ...` with ansibles command module and register a variable. Then use the registered variables `stdout` in `env:`.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#register-variables

Example:
Run twice and compare `date.stdout` from 1st run to `myvar.stdout` from 2nd run.

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: hargut
  tasks:
  - name: touch ~/myvar.txt
    file:
      path: ~/myvar.txt
      state: touch
  - name: read ~/myvar.txt into myvar
    shell: cat ~/myvar.txt
    register: myvar
  - debug:
      var: myvar.stdout
  - pause:
      seconds: 5 
  - name: write date into ~/myvar.txt
    shell: date > ~/myvar.txt
    register: date
  - name: read ~/myvar.txt into date
    shell: cat ~/myvar.txt
    register: date
  - debug: 
      var: date.stdout
```

The example shows that the file is read at each run.

Comment: This wouldn't really work since if file.txt's content changes , the var will stay with the old value, wouldn't it ? file.txt has a content that changes from time to time , therefore I'd like the var to have the command substitution as value so it will change the value when the file changes.

Comment: See above updated answer.

Comment: Thanks . Would that require to run the playbook every time I want to change the var's value?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`pipe` lookup plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/lookup/pipe.html):

```
environment:
  SSH_AUTH_SOCK: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'cat /root/file.txt') }}"
```

---

<sup>Remember lookup plugins are executed locally on the control machine, not on the target server. If the target server if different, you need to register the value in a separate task, as the other answer suggests.</sup>

<sup>Note also that you should use YAML notation to declare the `environment` dictionary (and it's not `env`).</sup>